# Algorithm for isomorphic groups?

Tags: algorithms, finite-groups, computational-mathematics, group-isomorphism, computational-algebra

As I understand

> There can't be a general algorithm to decide if two finite groups are isomorphic, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism_problem).

But are there efficient algorithms for all subgroups of $S_n$ for say $n=10$ or so?

I accepted the answer since it really was the answer (I misread Wikipedia and became a bit confused) but I would appreciate further suggestions on efficient algorithms for "small" $n$, for my blog on [Zet](http://forthmath.blogspot.se).

In Zet finite groups are represented as sets of permutations. Sets are implemented as bundles on stacks and permutations as vectors where for example $(4,3,2,1,5)$ represent $(1,4)(2,3)$.

I have an idea of a pseudo isomorphi, checking some characteristics as:

- The cardinals of the groups
- The cardinals of the sets of all (cyclic) subgroups
- Sorted vectors of the cardinals of the subgroups above

Comment: If you are thinking of practical algorithms, it would be helpful to agree how the two finite groups will be represented.

Comment: @hardmath, I will complement.

Comment: Have a look at the [Subgroups of symmetric groups](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_groups) page at the Group Props Wikia.  They catalog the possible subgroups up through $S_8$ in detail.  Since your finite groups are already represented as permutation groups, it should be fairly easy to identify which $n$ most narrowly encompasses the $S_n$ in which these are found.  Because there are finitely many possibilities, this is not a true problem of "complexity", but rather one of practical efficiency.

Comment: @hardmath: thanks for the ideas and the link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there are definitely algorithms to determine whether two finite groups are isomorphic or not.For a simple inefficient one, just look at all possible bijections and check using a multiplication table whether any of these bijections are homomorphisms.

What is true is that no such algorithm exists for finitely presented groups. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group).

Comment: Yes, for example there are implementations in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org). See [IsomorphismGroups](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap40.html#X81B79CC27F47D429) and links from that manual section.